# Concatenate Variable with JSON in JSX / React Native

Tags: json, react-native, jsx

So, I am building one of those weather apps with custom quotes based on the weather conditions.  The below code works...but as you can see, I have multiple quotes.  I generated a random number variable, which also works.  I'm trying to add that variable to the weatherCases JSX...I know it can be done, but man, I cannot figure out the syntax to make it work...

**Works on quote**

```
const weatherCases = {

   "clear sky": {
      title: "clear sky",
      quote1: "Custom quote 1.",
      quote2: "Custome quote 2",
      quote3: "Custom quote 3",
      ...
  }
}

function Forecast({ temp, weatherName, city }) {
  return ( 
    <View style={styles.forecastContainer}> 

      <View style={styles.forecastTopContainer}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.quoteText} >{weatherCases[weatherName].quote}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**What I'm trying to do to get random quote(this is one of a dozen edits to get that line to work:**

```
function Forecast({ temp, weatherName, city }) {

  const randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 30));
  console.log(randomNumber);
  //console.log(weatherName);
  return ( 
    <View style={styles.forecastContainer}> 

      <View style={styles.forecastTopContainer}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.quoteText} >{weatherCases[weatherName].quote.{randomNumber}}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to do to be like this

weatherCases[weatherName]["quote" + randomNumber.toString()]

for example the result randomNumber is 3 it will be like this

```
weatherCases["clear sky"]["quote3"]
```

Comment: Oh, jeezus.  I was so close!  Thank you, thank you @NaldPrabha

Comment: I'm glad it helped @EricMessick

if you think it solve your problem mark it as the correct answer so other people can make it as their reference to solve the same problem